# How to plot with pyqtgraph and multiprocessing?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, pyqtgraph

I'm trying to make a program that spawns 2 processes, one of which(`sender`) sends a random integer every second to the other process(`receiver`) and it plots a normal (Gaussian) distribution using the value.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time
import random
import os
import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui, QtCore
from pyqtgraph.dockarea import *

class PLT():
    def __init__(self):
        self.win2 = pg.GraphicsWindow(title="Basic plotting examples")
        self.win2.resize(1000,600)
        self.win2.setWindowTitle('pyqtgraph example: Plotting')
        self.p2 = self.win2.addPlot(title="Updating plot")
        self.curve = self.p2.plot(pen='y')

        #QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()   # ---> if it's in effect, the plotting window shows up, but the data exchange doesn't happen.

    def update(self, data):
        self.curve.setData(data)

class sender(mp.Process):
    def __init__(self, pipe):
        mp.Process.__init__(self)
        self.pipe = pipe

    def run(self):
        print('SENDER PID: ', os.getpid() )
        while True:
            value = random.randint(0, 10)
            self.pipe.send(value)
            time.sleep(1)

class receiver(mp.Process):
    def __init__(self, pipe):
        mp.Process.__init__(self)
        self.pipe = pipe

    def run(self):
        self.p = PLT()
        print('RECEIVER PID: ', os.getpid() )
        while True:
            integer = self.pipe.recv() 
            print(integer)  

            self.p.update(np.random.normal(size=(10,1000))[integer%10])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mp.freeze_support()
    print('MAIN PID: ', os.getpid() )

    out_pipe, in_pipe = mp.Pipe() 

    p1 = sender(pipe=in_pipe)
    p2 = receiver(pipe=out_pipe)
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
```

But it doesn't work as I expected. If I run it, it shows a pyqtgraph window which is blank(but I can see the data exchange). If I add `QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()`, it shows the window well, but now the data exchange doesn't work. What did I wrong? I'd appreciate it if I could get some advice or help.

Answer (score 2):

If that can help, I found that:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time
import random
import os
import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui, QtCore
#from pyqtgraph.dockarea import *

class PLT():
    def __init__(self):
        self.win = pg.GraphicsWindow(title="Basic plotting examples")
        self.win.setWindowTitle('pyqtgraph example: Plotting')
        #self.win.resize(1000,600)
        self.p2 = self.win.addPlot(title="Updating plot")
        self.curve = self.p2.plot(pen='y')

        #QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()   # ---> if it's in effect, the plotting window shows up, but the data exchange doesn't happen.

    def update(self, data):
        self.curve.setData(data)
        QtGui.QApplication.processEvents()   # <--- Here is the way to update the window.

class sender(mp.Process):
    def __init__(self, pipe):
        mp.Process.__init__(self)
        self.pipe = pipe

    def run(self):
        print('SENDER PID: ', os.getpid() )
        while True:
            value = random.randint(0, 10)
            self.pipe.send(value)
            time.sleep(.01)

class receiver(mp.Process):
    def __init__(self, pipe):
        mp.Process.__init__(self)
        self.pipe = pipe

    def run(self):
        self.p = PLT()
        print('RECEIVER PID: ', os.getpid() )
        while True:
            integer = self.pipe.recv() 
            print(integer)  

            self.p.update(np.random.normal(size=(10,1000))[integer%10])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mp.freeze_support()
    print('MAIN PID: ', os.getpid() )

    out_pipe, in_pipe = mp.Pipe() 

    p1 = sender(pipe=in_pipe)
    p2 = receiver(pipe=out_pipe)
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: don't forget to call `PLT()`  at the end of `__main__`